# Could humans wipe out all remaining wild vertebrates on Earth in one year, if no effort is spared in doing so?

Tags: internal-consistency, fauna, alternate-reality, alternate-earth

Humans already exterminated more than 50 % of wild vertebrates individuals since 1970 [1](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2014/sep/29/earth-lost-50-wildlife-in-40-years-wwf), [2](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-37775622).

I was wondering if it is possible to **wipe out the remaining 50 % in less than a year** ?

Note that, in this (alternative?) reality, Humans decide to spare no effort in this endeavour and desire to safeguard domestic species.

*Bonus question : Is the Earth still liveable after the extermination ?*

Comment: We’ve not lost 50% of _species_, we’ve lost 50% of wild vertebrate individuals. The proportion of species lost is far far lower.

Comment: @MikeScott You're right, question edited

Comment: well, we **are** vertebrates, and therefore on the last 50%. Do you wantall of us be exterminated as well? in any case, it would require a huge effort to destroy all of them...

Comment: By 'desire to safeguard domestic species', you mean the goal is to wipe out all non-domesticated species while leaving domesticated species(cows, dogs, chinchillas, etc.) intact, right? What about semi-domesticated animals, like [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domesticated_red_fox) foxes?

Comment: @Kepotx Agreed, but I don't think we can say we are "wild" vertebrates

Comment: @Giter In my idea, Humans want to keep domestic species such as chicken, cow (for food), sheep (for wool) but exterminate everything else which includes your red fox

Comment: Are they including themselves? If not definitely no, pest animals that live around humans ,like rats are very very hard to exterminate.

Comment: "Spare no expense." —John Hammond

Comment: Finally, I find it reassuring that nobody found so far a way to wipe out all wild vertebrates...

Comment: Since, as John points out, rats and other rodents are vertebrates, what is the source of the claim that we have killed half of all wild vertebrate individuals since 1970?  For larger wild species that sounds plausible, but rodents exist in vastly larger numbers and many rodent species interact very little with humans.

Comment: @tbrookside The source is linked from the question.

Answer (score 17):

No, it’s not within our power to kill all the [deep sea fish](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_sea_fish) within a year. Vertebrates that we kill higher up in the ocean will just fall to the sea bed and become food for them. And even if we could stop any organic matter from falling to the ocean floor, some vertebrates would still survive around geothermal vents.

Comment: But we could maybe poison vertebrates that we kill higher up in the ocean ? Radioactive wastes could also help

Comment: @user53220, radioactive waste does almost nothing in water, it's one of the best insulators against radioactivity there is.

Comment: Another point in favor of this answer: We've been actively fighting some vertebrates (rats and mice) for thousands of years without wiping them out. Seems unlikely we would suddenly succeed in a year.

Comment: @user535739: My original thought on seeing the question title was glass the planet, which would get the rodents. Then yeah I realized it won't get the deep sea fish either.

Comment: @user535733 how does that support _this_ answer?

Comment: @user535733 modern efforts to wipe out rats and mice are always moderated by our desire to not wipe out other wild animals: pesticides are formulated and dosed to prevent non-target populations from being exposed.  This does not necessarily reflect our inability to make a go at an all-out effort.  

If humans really committed themselves to causing ocean acidification, it wouldn't matter how *deep down* certain fish are: buildup of decaying organic matter would create an anoxic environment that would kill all water-breathing life.

Comment: @PinkSweetener Not within a year. The circulation of the deep ocean is very slow, and neither anoxic water nor poison will get to all parts of the deep ocean within anything like a year.

Comment: @MikeScott Are you suggesting it takes longer than a year for a molecule of oxygen to flow from surface water to the deep ocean (and therefor longer than a year for the absence of oxygen to be felt in the deep ocean)?  I'm not challenging you - I'm genuinely curious because if true, woah.

Comment: @PinkSweetener Yes, that’s exactly what I’m suggesting. “The thermohaline circulation engages the full volume of the ocean into the climate system, by allowing all of the ocean water to 'meet' and interact directly the atmosphere (on a time scale of 100-1000 years).” (https://eesc.columbia.edu/courses/ees/climate/lectures/o_circ.html)

Answer (score 6):

**No**

Humans have been trying to get rats to stop living off our largesse for millennia.  Nothing has worked so far.  If the survival of the human race meant we needed to no-fooling kill them all, we might be able to figure out something out.  Eventually.  But we are not going to develop and test new ways of killing off our rat problem, then deploy them everywhere around the globe (including in the poorest slums of the country with the worst GDP), and accomplish all of this in less than twelve months.

Comment: This is a great answer with a real world example.

Answer (score 3):

**[2,3,7,8-Tetrachlorodibenzodioxin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2,3,7,8-Tetrachlorodibenzodioxin), also known as TCDD, a part of [Agent Orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_Orange)**

destroys the

**Aryl hydrocarbon receptor**

vertebrates have, killing them if they consumed enough.

so if your humans really want to wipe out all wild vertebrates, they just have to spray everything with tons of TCDD, killing all vertebrates on land, and then pour it into the oceans, killing all vertebrates there.
it is solid, you have to solve it in something else ([chloroform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chloroform)) to be able to spray it properly. but because it is not a gas, it is easy to keep citys save. (of course you have to kill rats etc per hand)

so **humanity could kill all non domesticated vertebrates**.

but **earth stays liveable after that** since [some crops](https://www.foodrenegade.com/gmo-agent-orange-resistant-soy-corn/) sustain TCDD.

Comment: tons in this case being oceans of the stuff, which is likely beyond our capabilities to produce in a year.

Comment: How do they avoid it killing all the domesticated vertebrates (including humans)?

Comment: @MikeScott part of the collateral damage will be, of course, the death of all domesticated animals that are **exposed to** the TCDD.  So keep them indoors, or accept that they're going to die.

Comment: @RonJohn If you’re not spraying it indoors, you won’t kill all the rats and mice.

Comment: And probably killing people in the process? My home region was the testing ground for Agent Orange and there have been long held accusations of it causing cancer in locals. So that might covering the world and water ways with it will probably have unintended consequences for humans.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning your bonus question: **probably not**.

In some parts of the world (especially Africa), giand herds of herbivores forage and eat literally every single blade of grass, leaving behind tons of manure that fertilize the soil for the next generation of grass. Take these herds away and the circle of life stagnates. Young plants are suffocated beneath old grass and one spark sets the whole mess ablaze.

Same in the water: without herbivore fish, reptiles and marine mammals like sea cows to eliminate tons of algea and seaweed, many rivers and coast lines would become impossible to cultivate for domesticated aminals (fish farms).

This may not sound *too bad* at first, considering that humans wanted to get rid of all wildlife, but it could influence the locale climate and remaining wildlife quite severily.

- Noone wants bushfire to endanger the lifes of humans and domesticated animals
- Lack of vegetation results in lack of rain, causing draughts and crop failure
- If pests and parasites (like mosquitos) can't feed on wild animals, they will turn to domesticated animals, causing epidemics
- Invertabrates like jellyfish, insects, snails and octopuses will increase explosively, with unforseeable consequences